# Rails Ruby - How to create loop based on counted objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have to do some very repetitive calculations based on how many objects there are.

Example there are 4 objects.

Then I have to do these calculations:

```
1+2
1+3
1+4

2+1
2+3
2+4

3+1
3+2
3+4

4+1
4+2
4+3

1+3+2
1+4+3
1+2+4

3+2+1
3+4+2
3+2+4

4+2+1
4+3+1
4+2+3

1+2+3+4
```

How to do this in a non repetitive way of calculation all possibilities ?
I want to calculate all possibilities expect that a object my not appear twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
objs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
(1..objs.size).map {|i| objs.permutation(i).map {|o| o.reduce(:+) } }.flatten(1)
# => [
1, # 1
2, # 2
3, # 3
4, # 4
3, # 1+2
4, # 1+3
5, # 1+4
3, # 2+1
5, # 2+3
6, # 2+4
...
10, # 1+2+3+4
...
10 # 4+3+2+1
]
```

Comment: some details: the addition is a commutative operation, so you can simply do a `objs.combination(i)` instead of a permutation. And map + flatten(1) -> flat_map (ruby 1.9). `2.upto(xs.size).flat_map { |n| xs.combination(n).map { |cs| cs.inject(:+) } }`

Comment: @tokland how to do a combination? :)

Comment: Does it matter if a use example [14, 25] instead [1, 2]?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Array.permutations](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/permutation)

> When invoked with a block, yield all permutations of length n of the elements of ary, then return the array itself. If n is not specified, yield all permutations of all elements. The implementation makes no guarantees about the order in which the permutations are yielded.

Comment: Please include an excerpt or explanation. "Bare links" are better as comments.